# How to use generic type parameters for interface contravariance

Tags: c#, oop, generics

I have something that looks like the following scenario:

```cs
interface IExample<T>
{
  public IExample<T> First();
  public IExample<T2> Second<T2>();
}

class Foo<T> : IExample<T>
{
  public Foo() {}
  public IExample<T> First() => new Foo<T>() {};
  public IExample<T2> Second<T2>() => new Foo<T2>() {};
  public Foo<T> Third() => new Foo<T>() {};
}

public static class Main {
  public static void Run() {
    var bar = (new Foo<string>()).First().Third();
  }
}
```

This does not work, because `First()` returns an `IExample<T>`, which does not have `Third()`.

So in order to make it return itself, I have tried these two things:

```cs
interface IExample<T, out ExampleDerivedType>
{
  public ExampleDerivedType First();

  // Doesn't work because it expects Foo<T> instead of Foo<T2>
  public ExampleDerivedType Second<T2>();
}

class Foo<T> : IExample<T, Foo<T>>
```

```cs
interface IExample<T, out ExampleDerivedType>
// // Infinite recursion?
// where ExampleDerivedType : IExample<T, ExampleDerivedType> 

// // Does this kind of constraint even exist?
// where ExampleDerivedType is generic with one argument
{
  public ExampleDerivedType<T> First();

  public ExampleDerivedType<T2> Second<T2>();
}

class Foo<T> : IExample<T, Foo>
```

I know I can explicitly redefine the methods in this manner:

```
class Foo<T> : IExample<T>
{
  public Foo() {}
  IExample<T> IExample<T>.First() => First();
  public Foo<T> First() => new Foo<T>() {};

  IExample<T2> IExample<T>.Second<T2>() => Second<T2>();
  public Foo<T2> Second<T2>() => new Foo<T2>() {};

  public Foo<T> Third() => new Foo<T>() {};
}
```

But the solution I'm aiming for above is more appealing. I'm wondering whether it is

- Possible
- Possible in theory, but C# can not do it without help from either reflection or roslyn generators.
- Impossible, because it is logically flawed and the compiler lacks the information it needs.

Right now, I'm guessing it's the middle one, but I'd be happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: I don't think it is possible within C#'s type system. It is not flawed though - it is probably possible in type systems that have higher kinded types.

Answer (score 0):

As you said:

> `First()` returns an `IExample<T>`, which does not have `Third()`.*

So compiler does not know about existence `Third()`. In my view, it is possible to give a clue to compiler about that there is a method `Third()` by casting explicitly to `Foo<T>` as `IExample<T>` does not have `Third()`:

```
var bar = (Foo<string>)new Foo<string>().First();
var test = bar.Third();
```